# Eclipse Juno hanging on startup with OutOfMemory errors

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse Juno just updated itself and now it's hanging immediately after startup.  Running it from the console reveals the following errors:

```
ian@vega ~/Applications/eclipse> ./eclipse 
Exception in thread "Worker-1" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Worker-1"
Exception in thread "Worker-8" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Worker-8"
Exception in thread "State Saver" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "State Saver"
Exception in thread "Timer-0" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Timer-0"
```

I'm running Eclipse on OSX with the latest Java version:

```
ian@vega ~/Applications/eclipse> java -version
java version "1.7.0_08-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_08-ea-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.4-b01, mixed mode)
```

I thought maybe it needed a bigger heap so I created the following eclipse.ini file and gave it up to 4 gigs of RAM (my laptop has 16 gigs): https://gist.github.com/3804519

The eclipse.ini file appears to have been picked up as the splash screen no-longer displays, but it's still freezing.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

i ran into the same issue after updating eclipse juno today. for me creating an eclipse.ini (there was none beforehand) with the content
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
solved the problem. same for jdk 1.7.0_04 and 1.6.0_35 on macosx 10.8.2.
cheers!